# DynamoDBMappingException: no mapping for HASH key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When writing a DynamoDB Java App you can receive the 'no mapping for HASH key' error when writing or retrieving from a table if the table and its data model are not configured correctly. The full exception would be similar to:

`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: <YourClassNameHere>; no mapping for HASH key`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two helpful things to check here:

1) For your main setter for your hash key value make sure that the `@DynamoDBHashKey` notation is correctly set. `@DynamoDBAttribute` is NOT the correct one to use for your table's main hash key and neither is `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey`.

2) Make sure that the hash key is defined in the table definition:

```
        CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest()
                .withTableName("testtable")
                .withKeySchema(
                        new KeySchemaElement("id", KeyType.HASH)
                )
                .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L))
                .withAttributeDefinitions(
                        new AttributeDefinition("id", "S")
                );

        CreateTableResult result = amazonDynamoDB.createTable(createTableRequest);
```

The above table definition creates a table 'testtable' with a main index or hash key variable titled `id` and the type is `S` for string.

Additionally, if you are using inheritance, make sure that you don't have two functions with the same name that override each other. Dynamo will use the top-level getter and this can cause issues.

Comment: What if I have my HashKey attribute in an abstract class and final data structure is inheriting that? I am getting same error. How to resolve it.

Comment: Hi @KuldeepYadav. Have you managed to solve it? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @dbaltor Can't recall it :(

Comment: Thanks anyway @KuldeepYadav. I'll share here any solution I find, if any.

Comment: `@DynamoDBHashKey` attribute has to be declared in the class being serialized, the child.

Answer (score 24):

Make sure that your annotated mapped class's getters are declared `public`.

Comment: Thank you!  Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using @Data annotation (lombok.data), Try again after  removing it and generate getters and setters for all the Attributes(including the primary_key/partition_key).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the instance object that I was writing to DB for was of a **subclass** of the actual class that was annotated with DynamoDB annotations.

Was tricky to find out because the object param was declared as the parent class type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @Data annotation (lombok.data), Try again after removing it and generate getters and setters for all the Attributes(including the primary_key/partition_key).
Manually generate the constructor also. With and without aruguments. It helped me