# DynamoDBMappingException: no mapping for HASH key - even though I clearly mapped it

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

Okay, so I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798710/dynamodbmappingexception-no-mapping-for-hash-key) and I've looked at [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802020/error-while-using-dynamodb-aws-sdk-no-mapping-for-hash-key-because-of-naming-c).  Here's my specific problem:

I have a simple DynamoDB table called "server" with a single partition key "serverName".  Here's the table describe:

```
"table":{
    "attributeDefinitions":[{
        "attributeName":"serverName","attributeType":"S"
    }],
    "tableName":"server",
    "keySchema":[{
        "attributeName":"serverName","keyType":"HASH"
    }],
    "tableStatus":"ACTIVE",
    "creationDateTime":"Jul 29, 2017 12:46:36 PM",
    "provisionedThroughput":{
        "numberOfDecreasesToday":0,
        "readCapacityUnits":5,
        "writeCapacityUnits":5
    }
}
```

I have a Java table definition, like this:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="server")
public static class Server {
    private String serverName;
    private Room[] rooms;

    Server() {}

    Server(String serverName) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
        this.setRooms();
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="serverName")
    String getServerName() {
        return serverName;
    }
    void setServerName(String serverName) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can see in the describe that I have a HASH attribute of "serverName" and in my table definition in Java there's a `@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="serverName")`.

Can someone help me figure out why I'm *still* getting...

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Server; no mapping for HASH key
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.hashKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:119) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.105.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel$Builder.build(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:449) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.105.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$StandardTableFactory.getTable(StandardModelFactories.java:107) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.105.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.getTableModel(DynamoDBMapper.java:393) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.105.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:431) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.105.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.load(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:80) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.105.jar!/:na]
    at com.animationlibationstudios.channel.inventory.persist.dynamodb.ServerDynamoRepository.readServer(ServerDynamoRepository.java:110) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.animationlibationstudios.channel.inventory.persist.dynamodb.ServerDynamoRepository.readServer(ServerDynamoRepository.java:26) ~[classes!/:na]
```

(p.s. I'm using JDK 8 and com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.105)

Comment: You need to set a different access modifier for "getServerName". See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Your "getServerName" method is not public and DynamoDBMapper stumbles on it. Make it public and it should work:

```
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="serverName")
public String getServerName() {
    return serverName;
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Make sure that you've created table with a proper partition key definition that has "serverName" as partition key of the same type.

Here is how to do it:

```
DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);
CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = dynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(itemClass);
// Set your throughput here
createTableRequest.withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));

dynamoDB.createTable(createTableRequest);
```

Comment: Did the table describe I included not illustrate that I had created it just as you say? It was created through the AWS console rather than programmatically, but the describe was read via my code so the table exists and can be read - it's just complaining that there's no mapping for the hash.

Comment: I see, but one of the reasons of this error may be a mismatch between the structure of your table and your domain class. So my suggestion to check if you have same key name, same key type, and the same data type for your partition key.

Comment: Oh no! Amateur move! Although in my defense, IntelliJ "helpfully" suggested I make the methods package-private. I've now run headlong into an IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down...but the original error is taken care of. Thanks so much, @ivan